# if/else if statement not working, program always uses the first if

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to do a little homework. It's for practice if statement. What's wrong with my code ? It always ends by writing "Allez à l'hôpital" even if the "temperature" variable value is less than 39.

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace E4_2
{
  internal class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string texteÀAfficher;

        WriteLine("Veuillez indiquez la température du patient en celcius :");
        int temperature = Convert.ToInt32(Read());

        if (temperature > 39)
        {
            texteÀAfficher = "Allez à l'hopital";
        }
        else if (temperature > 38)
        {
            texteÀAfficher = "Prendre de l'aspirine ou de l'eau";
        }
        else if (temperature > 37)
        {
            texteÀAfficher = "Se reposer";
        }
        else
        {
            texteÀAfficher = "Prendre l'air et bien s'habiller";
        }
        WriteLine(texteÀAfficher);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you believe the value of `temperature` is less than 39 in this case?  If you haven't already, use the debugger, set a breakpoint on the first IF, and check the value of `temperature` when the breakpoint hits.

Comment: Console.Read returns a character (as an `int`).  If you typed `9` `6` `Enter` that would return the ASCII code for the character `9` which is `57`.  And `57 > 39`, so , yeah... read the (mostly terrible) docs for [Console.Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

The `if`/`else` statement is working.<sup>[1]</sup> That's not the problem. The simplest and most logical explanation is that the value of the `temperature` variable is actually larger than 39.

But you entered a temperature less than 39, right?

Well, yes, but...

You don't use the Console.Read() method properly. If you check its [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read), you will see that its return type is `int`. It returns a character (or rather a Unicode character code value) as an `int` value. This means, *Convert.ToInt32* isn't doing anything useful here, because converting an `int` value to an `int` yields just the same `int` value, obviously.

In consequence this means that the `temperature` variable contains the **Unicode  character code value** of whatever character you typed in first. If you were to type in `38`, the first character typed in is `3`. The character `3` has the Unicode character code value of 51. And the value 51 is obviously larger than 39.

Since Console.Read() only reads a *single* character, it's not really practical  (at least not in an easy manner) for inputting values with multiple characters/digits. Instead, i'd suggest to use *Console.ReadLine()* and parse the resulting string as an `int`:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int temperature = int.Parse(input);
```

---

<sup>[1] `if`/`else` is the "bread and butter" of control flow of pretty much almost every program ever written in C#. It works, it always had, always does and always will. It just has to work. Imagine the claim in the question title of `if`/`else` not working being true. Can you imagine, almost every meaningful C# program ever written would be broken and not functioning properly if `if`/`else` were broken. That `if`/`else` is not working is a quite extraordinary claim that's just not tenable without putting real hard evidence on the table.</sup>

Comment: While your first three paragraphs (and most of the next two) are correct, they are not constructive IMHO, and the OP never claims that `if` does not work fundamentally. You could have simply explained that `Read` reads one character (and it's unicode value) rather than a string of characters.

Comment: @DStanley, i disagree. The title clearly and obviously claims if/else not working.  That's the whole point why i wrote those two first paragraphs. But feel free to downvote if you think that pointing out if/else is actually working just fine is not constructive...

Comment: "What's wrong with my code" seems pretty clear that they are admitting that the problem is in their code, and just need to understand why. But, my main point was to encourage more constructive responses. In my opinion that does not warrant a downvote, but cancels out an upvote.

Comment: @DStanley, fair enough...